# Archive builds in hudson, Save old builds

Tags: hudson

Is it possible to configure hudson to save a copy of all the files per build?  As in everytime a build is triggered it grabs the files from the repository and stores them in a directory and builds it. Then when another build is triggered it grabs the files from the repository and stores it in a different directory to keep the build copies separate instead of having it update the same copy over and over again?

Comment: I think this is possible with some tweaking, but why do you want to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the archive plugin and set the filter to include as much as you want or you can use the clone workspace plugin. I don't see too much value in keeping all files, except if you want to run tests on the code that are so time consuming that you want to give a first feedback after the build and afterward run the tests in a separate job.